# Overwrite pdf file using tcpdf liberary

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to write pdf file using TCPDF open source liberay.

i use following code..

```
$html = <<<EOD
$prod
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->Output('pricepdf.pdf', 'FD');
```

I have dumped $html, and its okay.

now, the problem is with writing pdf file, I can't write the file .either no error is displayed. 
Onething, i should clear that, a file with same name is already exists in the given folder.

What i want is, to ovewrite 'pricepdf.pdf' file everytime, i run the script

Please guide me regarding this, Is this overwrite problem? or something else is creating problem? I am stuck at the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is not able to overwrite the file then you could check whether file exists and remove it.

```
if (file_exists('pricepdf.pdf')) unlink('pricepdf.pdf');
$pdf->Output('pricepdf.pdf', 'FD');
```

Turn on errors display to see if there is a problem with access to the file.

Comment: HOW CAN I TURN ON ERRO DISPLAY?

Comment: @NewBee  `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ini_set('display_errors','On');` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: CHANGED THE CODE, BUT STILL NO DISPLAY,

Comment: @NewBee you do not need to use CAPS letters. Do you have PDF output into the browser? Did you try to remove the .pdf file manually and to run your script again to check that file is created by the script?

Comment: got error   Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in /home1/teracast/public_html/pdf/tcpdf.php on line 20946

Comment: i removed the file, but still pdf not generated, i var_dumped my htmlsource..but file is not being generated

Comment: @NewBee    fatal error showed your problem. amount of memory allowed to be used by the script is slightly less than it needs. you may try to use `ini_set("memory_limit","70M");` or more, for example, but everything depends on the hosting.

Comment: @NewBee   it does not affect the 'format' of pdf. It just allows the script to use more memory and nothing else. Show an example of the 'lost format'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7432/discussion-between-n-e-w-b-e-e-and-cheery)

Comment: I found that it was XLS file problem